# Using a third party library inside a framework

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk, frameworks, static-libraries

I am building an SDK which uses some third party library (for example, AFNetworking).
As far as I know, if an app using my SDK also wants to use the same library, it will end up generating a compile error with duplicate symbols.

What is the best way to overcome it?

Thanks!

P.S. I understand that prefixing the library's files inside the framework with some SDK prefix will solve the problem, but is there a cleaner way?